# How to modify property values through reflection

Tags: java, reflection, field, rpc

I am currently writing an rpc framework. Now I hope that when the consumer adds @RpcReference to the attribute, the program can automatically scan and inject the attribute. However, after creating the proxy object, the familiar injection is unsuccessful. (Test project is not using spring)
`field.setAccessible(true); field.set(clazz, proxyConfig.get());`

```
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @RpcReference
    private UserService userService;
}

for (Field field : fieldList) {
    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();
    Class<?> aClass = null;
    try {
        aClass = Class.forName(fieldType.getTypeName());
        log.info("Class -> {}", aClass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    ProxyConfig<?> proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig<>(aClass);
    try {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        field.set(clazz, proxyConfig.get());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to set proxy instance to field: " + field.getName(), e);
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to set proxy instance to field: userService
    at com.dcy.rpc.bootstrap.DRpcBootstrap.reference(DRpcBootstrap.java:138)
    at com.dcy.rpc.Consumer.main(Consumer.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.dcy.rpc.UserService field com.dcy.rpc.service.impl.BookServiceImpl.userService to
```

I hope to complete the injection by modifying the attribute value

Comment: exception please, and which line is crashing?

Comment: A field of type `UserService` requires a value of type `UserService`. If the return value of `proxyConfig.get()` is not a subtype of `UserService`, you can’t set the field to that value. If you posted the complete exception, we could see which type the value had.